# Criar slide down menu responsive

Tags: html, css

Tenho um conjunto de links (que possuem uma estilização que faz com que pareçam botões) em meu site, eles funcionam adequadamente quando em um browser de computador ou tablet porém quando em smartphones gostaria de transformar estes `links (botões)` em `Slide Down Responsive` como é feita esta mudança de layout (por conseguinte o html)?

Código HTML:

```
<header>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="profile_information" class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <img id="profile_image" src="assets/images/misc/Tio-Sam.png">
                        <div id="profile_content">
                            <h1 class="nome"><strong>Nome</strong></h1>
                            <h2 class="desc">Descrição</h2>
                            <a href="#" class="social" id="email" target="_blank"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="social" id="linkedin" target="_blank"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="social" id="curriculum" target="_blank"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="social" id="github" target="_blank"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="social" id="sopt" target="_blank"></a>
                        </div>
                        <img id="claws" src="assets/images/misc/Claws.png">
                        <div id="menu">
                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info gray" href="index.html">Sobre mim</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info gray" href="conhecimentos.html">Conhecimentos</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info gray" href="#">Aprender e Atualizar</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info gray" href="contato.html">Contato</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info gray" href="experiencia.html">Experiência</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info gray" href="portfolio.html">Portfólio</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Imagem de como esta no computador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem de como esta no browser (portrait):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem de como deveria ficar (portrait):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Slide down aberto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se eu entendi o que você quer, você vai precisar disso http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp
Quando for até x resolução exibir de um jeito e por padrão outra

Comment: Ta usando Bootstrap? Consegue colocar pra emular ai?

Comment: @Sim estou usando bootstrap.

Comment: @MaiconCarraro já vi este `@media` mas o problema não se restringe somente a isto os `slide down menu responsive` que construi tinham uma estrutura de html diferente e não eram compostos por botões.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique Eu digo de quando sua resolução for x você oculta sua div de botões e exibe a div `slide down` e quando passa da resolução o inverso.

Comment: Entendo mais assim o html iria ficar meio grande correto.

Comment: @bfavaretto gostaria que me desse um feedback sobre as wiki de tags que proponho algumas são aceitas e outras não, são poucas mas gostaria de saber o motivo para que eu possa melhorar.

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz diferente do seu menu mais e só você modificar http://jsfiddle.net/xuw84x1s/